# Hadoop distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

This question may seem very trivial, but I'm new to Hadoop and currently confused by one question.

When starting the daemons, how can the appropriate files be located on the slave nodes?

I know you specify the masters and the slaves in the appropriate files, but how does it know about the location on the file system of that nodes(the path to where Hadoop is installed)?

Should I perhaps setup something like HADOOP_HOME (or HADOOP_PREFIX) for that?

Also, I read that in masters file you specify only the Secondary Name Node, while the Name Node and Job Tracker are considered to be located on the node from which your are calling start-all.sh. But what happens if you're not logged on that node, but on the other, client node? Maybe I didn't understand that part well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation on your different nodes of hadoop should be almost identical, and for that reason, you must specify HADOOP_HOME (i also specify HADOOP_PREFIX to the same location) pointing to your hadoop installation, in every node of your cluster.

Everyone of your nodes should be capable of connecting each other with ssh "password less" mode, so i believe that the last part of your question doesn't make much sense ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I specify these variables? I'm guessing in .bashrc? If so, I'm confused with the following - $HADOOP_PREFIX will be read when I start the terminal, BUT, that will enable to know on that machine where Hadoop is, but what about the other machines? Are you saying that it must be on the same location? And do you mean - master node needs to be able to communicate to all slaves? Maybe I'm wrong, but if they're all able to communicate, there would be a lot of keys that needed to be distributed to all nodes (to enable "password less" communication?

Comment: `$HADOOP_HOME` and `$HADOOP_PREFIX` should be in .bashrc, you are correct. It's very useful having hadoop in the same place in every node of your cluster (a lot of tutorials use `/usr/local/hadoop`), it will do some things a lot easier. You are right, you must copy several keys between ALL of your nodes (master with all slaves, and every slave with everyone else too)